# how to get overdue complaints using join two tables

Tags: postgresql

First table

```
Complaint_id         Completetion_date        Templateid
53035                 2018-11-16 00:00:00        5                
47956                2018-11-03 00:00:00        13
3953                 2017-11-27 00:00:00        17
```

Second table

```
Template_month                        id
8                                      5
6                                      13
4                                      15
2                                      17
```

In first table completion date is 16 Nov 2018 and tempalteid is 5 and in the second table id 5 have 8 month means need to calculate 8 months from 16 nov this is not overdue complaint. In the second row of first table completion date 2018-11-03 00:00:00   having templateid 13 and in the second table there is 6 month means periods is overdue then in the result 3953 is overdue id

I am using this query

```
select complaint_id 
from complaints as comp 
INNER JOIN template ON comp.templateid=template.id 
where comp.completion_date::date + ('interval ' || template.template_month::text || ' month')
```

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: date + text
LINE 1: ...teid=template.id where comp.completion_date::date + ('interv...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 129

Comment: `first_table.Completetion_date::date + interval (second.Template_month::text || ' month')`

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "template"
LINE 1: ...e.id where comp.Completion_date::date + interval (template.t...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 141

Comment: Try to understand what the value is calculated by the condition I give to you... and then think how to use it for to solve your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an interval like that. To have a variable number of months,  create a 1 month interval and multiply it with your number of months.

You also need to compare the result of adding the interval to the completion date to something. I assume you want to compare it to "today":

```
select comp.complaint_id 
from complaints as comp 
  JOIN template as tmpl ON comp.templateid = tmpl.id 
where comp.completion_date + interval '1 month' * tmpl.template_month < current_date;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/JGNX75589

Comment: They could also use `+ make_interval(months => tmpl.template_month)`. See https://rextester.com/BBOM3893